# Upgrading PHPUnit from 4.8 to 5.5

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

We upgraded our systems to PHP7.0.
This required us to upgrade PHPUnit to 5.5, as 4.8 doesn't properly support PHP7.
This produces the following error, which nets a failure in phpunit in our CI

```
PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::getMock() is deprecated,
use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::createMock() or
PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::getMockBuilder() instead
```

What it looks like now is that we have to touch 1200+ unit tests to refactor how we build our mocks.

Is there either a way to suppress that warning, or, quickly convert our uses of `getMock` to `createMock`, which seems to work differently enough that a global find/replace won't cut it?

Comment: There's pattern called Adapter. Take a look at it.

Comment: Set error reporting to hide deprecations? `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);` http://php.net/function.error-reporting

Comment: @GerardRoche I think, that it's bad idea to hide deprecation. We are working to make our project as up-to-date as we can. It's just the avoiding of problem.

Comment: @jaro1989 I'll grant you, yes hiding the deprecations is a concern if it is seen as a solution. But Umbrella also asks if there is a way to suppress the warning. Temporarily suppressing the deprecation notices until everything is updated to the new API I think is ok.

Comment: @GerardRoche Temporarily is the word. But such lazy programmers as I will forget about it as soon as they press ctrl+S. In a year everywhere on stackoverflow you will see this: "Stop using getMock(), use createMock() instead" on every comment. So just temporarily.

Comment: @jaro1989 Lazy programmers :)  I guess suppressing deprecations could end in tears. You could wrap the error suppression in a time sensitive clause where the errors are suppressed for n days. Suppressing the deprecations is really only useful so that you can address the other compatibility issues first.

Comment: Sure, you can work around the deprecation like that. But the proper way is to migrate your tests, sorry about that. `getMock()` etc. are gone in PHPUnit 6: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/ChangeLog-6.0.md

Comment: Incidentally, We've got a clean run of PHPUnit locally, but, our PHPCI installation still reads PHPUnit as failing -- with no errors.  Same with php_loc, failing with no errors according to PHPCI.

Comment: Just one more rant. 1200+ is like nothing, I have probably closer to 12000 cases of getmock used... overall I highly dislike this change. Mockbuilder is incredibly verbose... And can't use createMock, since for time being (even if just couple months) I have to keep php5 compat... So yeah, highly disapointed with now required verbosity of so called "fluent" interfaces (which can be good in some cases, but here it's just crazy verbose compared to getMock).

Comment: And just to sound a little less sour, in hopes Sebastian reads this, you still doing a great work even if I disagree with this change. After having/needing to work with unit testing in java (well not too much for now), phpunit seems just so much more pleasant to use, and seems more polished. Much much more flexible, though possibly java bing statically typed might limit them somewhat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create additional test class called TestAdapter which will extend PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase

```
class TestAdapter extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
    * Override your deprecated method
    */
    public function getMock()
    {
        return $this->createMock();
    }
}
```

Then you just need to extend all of your tests from this class.

Comment: We could literally copy `TestCase::getMock()` into our `TestAdapter` class with no faults, since apparently none of the things `getMock()` uses are marked deprecated.  Though, admittedly that seems counter to whatever their motives were for deprecating it.

Comment: Yup. Also there're some benefits from this additional layer. You could move your duplicated code into it and then segregate it as you need. It's about mocking same object and creating of dummy data-arrays etc. After you could name it UnitTestHelper and you would never regret about that

Comment: As it happens, we already had such a class, it just didn't occur to me at the time this intermediate class was where we were doing our `getMock()` calls, which is why all our tests (which already use the MockBuilder) were yielding this warning.  This makes this solution not only simple, but (should have been) obvious for us.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. I did run a regex replace to fix `getMock()` deprecated entries.

> `->getMock\(([^)]+)\)` replaced with `->getMockBuilder($1)->getMock()`

Hope that helps

Comment: Much better future-compatible solution, thanks!
Even better is context aware Rector ugprade (I work on): https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/blob/ac60f8ac093bea3bf916b588d8cfd803d7745cca/config/set/phpunit/phpunit60.yaml#L5